# Using motionPie: I'm stuck trying to install a camera driver

Tags: webcam, driver

I'm trying to set up a raspberry pi for these tasks:

- streaming video over a network
- listening to commands (I'm not yet sure how to do that) over network
- parse commands and control a slave connected to the I2C bus (I've done that successfully with raspbian)

The first thing I did was to download the latest [motionPie](https://github.com/ccrisan/motionPie/releases) release (20140928), write it to the SD card and boot. That worked well, I can see the web interface using a browser on a different PC.

The first problem is that the web interface shows an error message: `Unable to open video device`. I have an old Philips SPC230NC webcam connected to a USB port that I'd like to try. Maybe the system just doesn't have a driver for i, so I tried to download this driver: http://www.saillard.org/linux/pwc/ (latest release pwc 10.0.12-rc1). However I couldn't unzip it using

```
tar xjf pwc-10.0.12-rc1.tar.bz2
```

which gave me an error message

```
tar: bzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
```

Indeed I cannot find `bzip2` on the system. How can I install it? Is my plan (using above webcam/linux combo) even reasonable?

Currently I'm just trying to sort out how I can accomplish the three tasks I outlined above. I'm also willing to buy a raspberry pi cam if I need to; they're not that expensive after all.

Any suggestions?